# Find alpha-numeric value in a field with several alpha-numeric values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a list of alpha-numeric values and I need to search my SQL Server database for entries that contain these "words".

Unfortunately the data in the DB is of very bad quality.
The varchar field that might have these values can contain (a single or) several alpha-numeric values that are seperated by " " "," or "-". The length of the values varies.

Let's say I'm looking for database records with the value "X1337" and my DB entries look like this:

```
99802 99803 X1337
99802 X9803 102379 70X1337
99842 99893 , X1337 12608, X25663 125498
42X13379
X1337, 99802 99803
X1337
```

My goal is to find the following 4 entries:

```
99802 99803 X1337
99842 99893 , X1337 12608, X25663 125498
X1337, 99802 99803
X1337
```

I must NOT find the following 2 entries:

```
99802 X9803 102379 701337
42X13379
```

Is this task achievable using SQL?

My thought was to apply a pattern to something like this but I'm not really good with patterns:

```
DECLARE @numberstolookfor TABLE (Number varchar(60))
INSERT INTO @numberstolookfor VALUES ('1027903')
INSERT INTO @numberstolookfor VALUES ('X1337')

SELECT *
FROM [myDB]
Where DBFIELDINFO like (SELECT Number FROM @numberstolookfor)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to be efficient `LIKE` users here, and we can try to cover all possible use cases where `X1337` might appear:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    ' ' + DBFIELDINFO LIKE '% X1337 %' OR
    ' ' + DBFIELDINFO LIKE '% X1337,%' OR
    ' ' + DBFIELDINFO LIKE '% X1337';
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

We first add a single space to the start of the field to be checked.  After doing this, we only need to check for `[ ]X1337` followed by space or comma (for occurrences at the start or middle), or `[ ]X1337` followed by nothing, for occurrences at the very end of the field.

Comment: This is incredibly helpful, thanks for the quick and solid answer. I don't know why I thought I had to do it with a single pattern when this solution with a few 'OR' works just fine. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I _think_ the first two terms in my `WHERE` clause can be condensed down to: `LIKE '% X1337[, ]%'`, _but_ I prefer leaving it as-is.  Note that if SQL Server supported regex like, then you really could use a single pattern: `[ ]X1337([, ]|$)`